# Passing Data from one form to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms namely "MainForm" and "SubForm"
Now "Mainform" has a button and a textbox. Upon clicking the button, "SubForm" should be opened while MainForm will also remain opened.
Now SubForm has a text box and an OK button. User will input the value in the textbox and on clicking OK, SubForm should be closed and MainForm textbox text should be changed to the text which has been entered in SubForm textbox.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the constructor for `SubForm` and add a property this way:

```
Private sValue As String = String.Empty

Public New(myText As String)
    SomeText = myText
    TextBox1.Text = SomeText
End Sub

Public Property SomeText As String
    Get
        Return sValue
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        sValue = value
    End Set
End Property

'on OK button click event
 SomeValue = TextBox1.Text
```

Then in `MainForm` (on button click):

```
Using sf As SubForm = new SubForm(Me.InitialText.Text)
    Dim dlg As DialogResult = sf.ShowDialog()
    If dlg = DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.InitialText.Text = sf.SomeText
    End If
End Using
```

Other settings:

`SubForm`:

- `AcceptButton` property - refers to `OK` button
- `OKButton.DialogResult` = `OK`
- `TextBox1` -  the name of textbox for user input

`Main form`

- `InitialText` - the name of textbox

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties  It is much less typing to us Auto-implemented properties.

Comment: @Mary, good point. I didn't use that, but i did it intentionally.